# Resizing UITableView with a table header in UIScrollView using auto layout

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have one simple UIView and three tables nested in the UIScrollView. The first two tables *have table headers included*. The third (orange) table has no header view and it is resized correctly according the data it uses. The picture displays the closed state of the scroll view. UITableView_A and UITableView_B are closed, UITableView_C opened. The data are ready for use in all tables, and also the cells are being created.

Also in xib I have connected the layout constraints to the properties from the subclass of UIScrollView. The constants are specific sizes as UIScrollView demands it for its nested views.

**The issue:**
The views are being resized correctly but when I update the constants for heights of the tables without the header views (the first two tables, green and pink) I manipulate only with **the header views**. Which is odd. The auto layout constraints for the green and the pink table are setup correctly in the xib file. I was checking the resized tables in the simulator using introspection tool and I realized the first two resized tables are not tables BUT only the header views.

The height of cells is 44 and headers also 44. The tables are not scrollable.

**Closed state:**
[image]

**Opened state**
[image]

When I update the auto layout constants related to any table I call this line afterward

```
[self layoutIfNeeded]; //(scroll view)
```

### UPDATE 1:

When I remove the header views from the tables, then the resizing works perfectly for the tables. I am really curious why I manipulate just with the header views instead of the whole table when the constraints is defined on the table view NOT on the table header view.

Comment: Why do you have 3 table views AND a scroll view?

Comment: There are different data in each of them. And also there are simple views nested in the scroll view. I need to hide/open each table independently.

Comment: Why not just do ONE table view with 3 sections?

Comment: Thank you. It could be a solution if there were no other views placed among the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the table header views with the section header views and the resizing works smoothly. I'd be glad to know the explanation for the previous problem.